# Bitwise Operator is it useful?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Im new to java and im planning on skipping this topic because even if I learn it I might forget it if Im not using it. What application there that uses bitwise operators? for some experience programmer do you use it always or not?

Comment: Um... flags enumerations, file formats that weren't made by sane people, reassembling packets, etc., etc.?

Comment: Learn it anyway. It'll be better to be familiar that totally lost when you need it.

Comment: Learn it because it will give you insight into what's going on at the register level (bits and bytes).

Comment: But if im not using it i might forget it, so its useless i think. Im familiar with bits and how to convert decimal to bits so maybe its not hard if I study it the moment I need it.

Comment: @minitech, the file formats that store binary information are the sane ones. All that XML rubbish is an insidious plot by harddrive manufacturers to sell more product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subnet masking uses bitwise operation to transform specific IP addresses into masked network addresses. If you plan on studying computer networks, you might want to learn it. It's pretty easy to learn. Shouldn't take you more than 10 or 15 minutes. If you're in Discrete Math, a lot of the stuff you cover in there is pretty abstract, but if you know it well it can be applied to lots of other things in helpful ways.